# Identify an array having multiple null values but a single number type value/element in JavaScript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
Input : var arr = [2,null,null,null];
Output : true

Input : var arr = [null,null,5.6,null];
Output : true

Input : var arr = [2,null,null,5.6];
Output : false

Input : var arr = [null,null,null,null];
Output : false
```

Need an efficient way to identify an array having one valid number element and rest all can be null.

**null** and **Number** type element are only two types we are considering in here.

Comment: This should get you started: `arr.every(v => v === null || Number.isInteger(v)) && arr.some(v => Number.isInteger(v))`. Voting to close, since this isn't an appropriate stackoverflow question (lacks effort and a specific focus).

Comment: How is `[null,null,5.6,null]` outputs true but `[2,null,null,5.6]` outputs false?

Answer (score 0):

You could take a variabel for counting numbers an initialize with `-1` and check this value at the end. Inside of `every` check either `null` or if number increment count and returnthe result of the negated count.

```js
const
    check = array => {
        let count = -1;
        return array.every(v => v === null || typeof v === 'number' && !++count)
            && !count;
    };

console.log(check([2, null, null, null]));    //  true
console.log(check([null, null, 5.6, null]));  //  true
console.log(check([2, null, null, 5.6]));     // false
console.log(check([null, null, null, null])); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Set and conditions to filter

```js
 function ck(arr) {
      s = [...new Set(arr)].sort()
  return (s.includes(null) && s.length == 2 && !isNaN(s[0]))?true:false
      }
      console.log(ck([2, null, null, null]))
      console.log(ck([null, null, 5.6, null]))
      console.log(ck([2, null, null, 5.6]))
      console.log(ck([null, null, null, null]))
```

Answer (score 0):

The only efficiency aspect here is the early false exit. The true exit must compare all values.

```
let test_array = arr => {
   let numbers = 0;
   let length = arr.length;
   for(let i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
      if(arr[i] !== null) ++numbers;
      if(numbers > 1) return false;
   }
   return (numbers == 1);
}
```

Looking for efficiency only makes sense if you have long arrays. Otherwise the following one liner would suffice

```
arr.reduce((r, v) => r += (v !== null), 0) == 1
```